# subscribe to an email list button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a button that will change the subscribed column on a user table turn from 0 to 1 or vice versa but I've never tried to change the db outside of the new or edit page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

The link would be: <%= button_to 'subscribe', :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :put, :remote => true %>

Define a method called subscribe on the user model

Define a new action in the user controller like

```
def subscribe
  @user=Content.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(:subscribe => true)
    flash[:success] = "User subscribed"
    ajax_redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    #render partial with error message or something
  end
end
```